# Submit with value

Tags: javascript, url

I use the regular `<a href="javascript:document.form.submit()">` to submit data from a form, which I guess is equivalent to an anonymous button: `<input type=submit>`

While this is fine for the default-behaviour, I also have a special button `<input type=submit name=special value="special behaviour">` which sets the variable `$_REQUEST['special']`.

How can I convert this button into a `javascript:` URL that submits the form and also sets the `$_REQUEST['special']` variable?

Comment: try `javascript:document.form.special='<value goes here>';document.form.submit()`

Comment: Use an `onsubmit` handler instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with

```
<form name="myform">
    <input name="special" type="hidden"/>
</form>

<a href="javascript:document.forms['myform'].special.value='<value goes here>';document.forms['myform'].submit()">dd</a>
```

Demo: [Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2AwWx/1/), [Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2AwWx/2/)